# Is there a way to route messages according to the stash size in Akka(Scala)

Tags: scala, akka

I have a worker pool with load balancing, which is defined as follows:

```
class Worker(workerNr: Int) extends Actor with Stash
...
val workers = (1 to poolSize).map(c => context.actorOf(Props(() => new Worker(c)).withDispatcher("stash-dispatcher"), "worker" + c))
val pool = context.actorOf(Props[Worker].withRouter(SmallestMailboxRouter(routees = workers)))
...
pool ! Request("do something")
```

Now this worker actor isn't stateless and uses become after he forwards a request to another actor (which does the actual work) and stashes all following requests away, until he gets a response for the current request (which can take a while). Then he sends the response to the requesting actor, unstashes all stashed messages and handles the next request after switching back with unbecome.

```
case request@Request(_) => {
   val requestor = sender
   requestHandler ! request
   become {
     case response@Response(_) => {
       requestor ! response
       unstashAll
       unbecome
     }

     case msg => stash
   }
}
```

My problem is the SmallestMailboxRouter, I am using. It routes the messages to the worker with the smallest mailbox. But since the workers aren't blocking, and stash messages away, which they can't handle at the moment, their mailboxes are always pretty empty (in contrast to their stash).

I would like to have a router, which routes the messages to the worker with the smallest stash. I thought of implementing a Router myself which does that, but looking at the [implementation of Stash](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Stash.scala), it seems that I can't even access the stash size, because the stash itself is private to the stash trait.

```
private var theStash = Vector.empty[Envelope]
```

Is there a way to do this, or is this the wrong approach to implement a worker pool with load balancing?

Comment: Why not keeping a record of the size of each stash at router level, meaning, a map or something that would be updated each time a message gets routed to a given worker?

Comment: Perhaps this pattern is something that might fit your problem: http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/akka-work-pulling-pattern/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering this question you asked in the end: *"Is there a way to do this, or is this the wrong approach to implement a worker pool with load balancing?"*.

Here is the way I implemented worker pool with load balancing:

There is a single `WorkerManager` actor that receives job requests. It puts them in it's own queue right away. This can be any kind of queue that holds job requests `Job`, for example `Queue[Job]`. `WorkerManager` also has a list of workers with jobs assigned to them, something like `List[(ActorRef, Option[Job]]`.

Whenever `WorkerManager` receives a `Job` request and right after it puts it in the queue it can check if there is any idle actor in the list of assigned jobs, i.e `(ActorRef, None)`. If so, then it sets the assigned job in that list for that worker actor and sends a `Job` message to that actor. If there are no idle workers `WorkerManager` simply does nothing, and waits for one of the workers to reply with job completion message.

On the other hand whenever `Worker` finishes processing the `Job` it replies back to `WorkerManager` with that `Job` ID and `WorkerManager` removes that job from the list of assigned/running jobs. If `Worker` fails it can be restarted with the same job if desired.

You can chose who replies back to the `Client` - it can be a `Worker` or a `WorkerManager`. For these purposes you might want to send client `ActorRef` together with `Job` message to the `Worker`.

There is no problem in concurrent queue modification or any race conditions related to maintaining the queue because Actors process messages one by one, thus `WorkerManager` will always process the queue sequentially.

Additionally `Worker` can be a state machine with state transition timeouts to avoid waiting for it forever.

Workers can be either created by `WorkerManager` or they can be created separately and register with `WorkerManager` by sending a registration message. There could be multiple `WorkerManager` actors getting their tasks using one of the routing algorithms (round-robin, etc).

EDIT

Apparently there is a pattern for it :) - it's called work pulling pattern or something.

Comment: There's a writeup on the official Akka blog: http://letitcrash.com/post/29044669086/balancing-workload-across-nodes-with-akka-2